# Angular5 inserting element in an array while displaying it with ngfor

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular5

I have an array (config.lensTab) of objects which I display with an ngFor in my Html :

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of config.lensTab; let i = index;">
          <th scope="row">{{ i + 1}}</th>
          <th><label></label>
          <input [(ngModel)]="item.radius" class="form-control"
                             type="number" step="0.01" name="radius-{{i}}</th>
[...]
```

I've added a '+' button which would insert an element in my array in a given index (idx) :

```
  public addLens(idx: number) {
           let toAdd = new LensModel(0, 0, 0,
           new MaterialModel('Air', 0), 0, 0);
           this.config.lensTab.splice(idx + 1, 0, toAdd);
     }
```

When I display the content of the array with console.log, the insert operation seems to work correctly. However in my html view the line next to the new line has the same value than this new line.

I give you an easy example for understanding :

```
Tab : [RED, GREEN, WHITE] --> add "BLUE" at index 1 ---> [RED, BLUE, BLUE, WHITE]
```

What am I doing wrong ?

**EDIT** : this is how I initialized my config object

```
this.config = new ConfigModel();
this.config.lensTab = [];

this.config.lensTab.push(new LensModel(1, 2, 3, new MaterialModel('Acier', 12), 4, 5));
```

**EDIT2** :

[Before clicking the "+" button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Bzsq.png)

[after clicking the "+" button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1rIl.png)

plunker : https://embed.plnkr.co/DghlRr/

Comment: Have you modified the changeDetection of the component.?

Comment: I don't know what it is so probably not

Comment: can you  provide some code where config is initialised.?

Comment: is there any chance by which the config.lensTab gets initialised again in your code.?

Comment: It isn't initialised again, to reproduce the bug the only function I call after constructor is the addLens function

Comment: try interpolating the config in HTML and see if it is changing. {{ config }}

Comment: Sorry, I have deleted my answer, I was confused with something else.

Comment: @FranklinPious Ok so I tried your solution, in my loop I display config value with {{ config.materialTab[i].name }} and changes are correct.

So it would means that the problem is about the input value

Comment: @AshishRanjan no problem, thanks for your help anyway

Comment: @ArthurChennetier try {{ config | json }} outside the loop and check.

Comment: It is changing with the correct values

Comment: can u provide the current output and the desired output.?

Comment: I edited my post with two pictures, when I clicked the first "+" button it is supposed to add an empty line (this is working). But as you can see the last line is also empty whereas in my config object (json) datas are correct

Comment: Does it make any difference if you change NgModel to value?

Comment: If I make this change the last line is not "overrided" anymore but my inputs are not detected by the model so the config value does'nt change

Comment: Does this make any difference ? Changing the ngModel

<input [(ngModel)]="config.lensTab[i].radius" class="form-control"
                             type="number" step="0.01" name="radius-{{i}}</th>

Comment: No it doesn't change anything

Comment: If you can provide a plunker, maybe i can figure it out for u

Comment: Ok i'm creating one

Comment: there it is : https://embed.plnkr.co/DghlRr/ thank you for your help I appreciate it

Comment: @ArthurChennetier did the answer work for you.?

Comment: @Artory if you have used an anchor tag and applied click event for adding the item to array, then it will cause problem. I can't see your html tag containing event so can't say but this worked for me with <button> and not with <a> element.

Comment: @Ahsan I manage to resolve this with the Franklin Pious's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used trackBy function of the angular so that ngFor detects the change.

https://plnkr.co/edit/iyXOgVSwN2VuJT64YxrT?p=preview

```
<div *ngFor="let item of config.lensTab; let i = index; trackBy: trackByFn">

    trackByFn(index, item) {
return index;  }
```

Have updated the plunker.